# user folder disappear, Can't login as root and only guest user works

Tags: login, user-profile

the problem is that my user folder is missing my `home/` directory is empty , i can't log in as the **admin** account, stuck in **lightdm** loop but only the **guest** user works but with no access to root .... even with the live cd can't see my user directory the only thing that indicate that all my folders still exist that the size of that partition is the same.. allways having the same used space that after the problem accure .
what can i do ? thnx

Comment: i found it after digging inside the system it's located root/.local/share/Trash/files/   have any idea how that accured

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go into recovery mode (go down to the advanced options in the grub menu) and select "drop to root console" or something to that effect. enter "mount -o rw,remount /"
type "useradd username -m -s /bin/bash" with your username instead of username, then "passwd username" and enter the password you want. Finally, to make it admin, type "adduser username sudo" again using the username of the account instead of the word username.

Comment: sorry but i don't need to add a user. my account still there it's just not reachable because the user directory is gone .. it's somewhere there but i can't find it

Comment: create another user with a different name, copy that user's home folder under the name of the old one, and you will at least be able to log in as the old user, but if you deleted the home folder for that user then you're out of luck

Comment: if it has been moved to the trash, then use a root terminal from recovery mode to go to /home/username/.local/share/Trash and check what, if anything, resides there. If it is your home folder, then just mv it from there to where it belongs

Comment: or just use in a root prompt cd /home/.username/ if you think it got hidden for some reason

Comment: no it's not hidden and for sure i didn't delete it and i can't access the /home/username/.local/share/Trash because i can't even access the username directory . thank you

Comment: that's really odd. Try running some sort of chckdsk and see if it is just a corrupt directory inode. It may be just that the identifier is corrupt, though everything inside is still in existence.